# What is good software for video editing under Linux?

Tags: software-recommendation, linux

I plan to create some homemade video lectures and I am under Linux. Is there comfortable open-source tool that has the following abilities:

- to clear noise
- to have a few sound channels
- to allow adding a slide screen in part of the video screen
- to add titles and labels over the footage
- to have simple effects

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/good-open-source-video-editors

Though its not asking specifically for Linux and mainly for windows.

Comment: Nope, I don't think those are for Linux... Open-source means ~free.

Comment: He also searches for Linux tools and many are for Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of answers regarding open source on this answer: [Good open source Video Editors?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/good-open-source-video-editors)

If you specifically target Linux I'd suggest [Lightworks](http://www.lwks.com/) or [Kdenlive](http://kdenlive.org/). Lightworks isn't open source yet but is announced to be after the mac release is finished.

Both a great option for video editing under Linux and fullfill your requirements. Lightworks has only one downside, that being you need to register it on the first start with a free Lightworks account. After that you don't have to connect to the internet again.

If OpenSource is the most important factor I suggest to go with Kdenlive.

Comment: Its actually a suprisingly solid tool despite the kind of boring website for it. NLE's for Linux have been pretty crap in the past. Would recommend it over a lot of free tools for windows.

Answer (score 3):

[Blender](http://www.blender.org/) has video editing options, and of course, it is free. Check it out.

Comment: It seems to be a 3D modeller software, but thanks a lot for sharing. :)

Comment: It is not only that. It is a video editing tool check this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1sODml0PBlo

Comment: I later realized your point. But I still don't have the right to vote up your answer :-/

Comment: Don't mind about voting, just download the app and try it, it is an impressive tool. Hope the info will be usefull for someone else. Enjoy :-)